# Digital Ocean API key change how to update with doctl?

Tags: digital-ocean, api-key

My old Digital Ocean API key was deleted and a new one created. How do I update this to the new value? 
`doctl auth init` points to the old value. I did not see any documentation on this. I unistalled doctl and ran `rm -rf $HOME/Library/Application Support/doctl` then reinstalled and still pointing to invalid key.

Thank you for your time and energy in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Jeff the following command can be used to update your key
`doctl auth init --access-token <your-new-key>`
this should update the configs for further use as well. If not check your `config.yaml` to ensure the token was updated.

Comment: I'm constantly getting: `Error: Unable to use supplied token to access API:`

Comment: If using an authentication context, it seems that the `doctl auth init --access-token <token>`  only works the first time, but for renewing a token it does not work (even if adding the `--context <context_name>` flag). 
I had to modify the token directly in `~/.config/doctl/config.yaml` as suggested in the answer.